# Cartoon sync studio equipment

Tags: software

Im thinking in buying equipment specially for this sort of work. Is there any specialised software for this job or studios use most popular ones that we all use in every day work?

Comment: Do you just mean sound effects and dialogue recording and editing?

Comment: Voiceover to be exact. From English to other languages.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're after, but all you need is a mic, a preamp of some sort & software that can record/manipulate audio in sync to video. Cubase can do that - Nuendo may be more sophisticated, but Cubase can do it. Two screens [or more] helps, but isn't *absolutely* vital.